# SetWinEventHook and GetMessage c++

Tags: c++

I would like to set some events with SetWinEventHook and wait.
After five events I want to exit from the message loop. The problem is that the code stucks in getMessage without entering in the loop.
The Callback function is correctly called whenever an event occurred.

```
HWINEVENTHOOK hEvent = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, NULL,
    WinEventProcCallback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook0 = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE,
    NULL, WinEventProcCallback, 0, 0,
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook1 = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY,
    NULL, WinEventProcCallback, 0, 0,
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

    while (ret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (cont >= 5) break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        cont++;
        std::cout << "Reached : " << cont << std::endl;
    }
```

How I can solve this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
```

is equal to

```
if (ret = (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0))
```

Comment: Sorry  I haven't understand the meaning of your response, in one way or another the code still block on getMessage.

Comment: You may be want to write like this `while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
while (ret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        return;
    }
```

the if statement won't be true in this case, so you won't get to the return.
ret can't be greater than 0 and -1 at the same time